# C remove element from chars array

Tags: c

I have an array called names
.
The element to remove is Stephanie Conley

```
char names[30][50]={"Henry Bush","Stephanie Conley","Ronald Boon","Aura Henry","Larry Knox"};

main(){
int i,indice = 1; // 1 = Stephanie Conley
int n=4; // total number of elements in the array

 for (i=indice;i<=n-1;i++)
   names[i]=names[i+1];

}
```

Error : assignment to expression with array type

Comment: `char names[30][50]` change to `const char* names[30]`. Or if you actually want to copy the data round, use strcpy.

Comment: The C language doesn't support assignment of arrays. And you can't remove any member of an array. You should replace the member of the array with the successor. You should also check if you need a two-dimensional array. Try to use an array of pointers to char arrays.

Comment: An array of arrays is still an array. :)

Comment: const char* names[30] works but can i do it without pointer ?

Comment: @Lundin I don't think it should be closed. First, it is not a complete duplicate of the other question, and, second, none of the answers truly explain why you cannot assign an array, but happily take its address. And I think that is the trap the OP (and many others) fall into.

Comment: @GermanNerd Feel free to suggest a better duplicate. Though I think using canonical dupes that roughly answer the question is fine, when the OP is asking for the contents of a beginner-level C programming book. We probably have hundreds of duplicates regarding problems when assigning strings with the `=` operator.

Comment: I was actually looking for a solution without using pointer, anyway that work           ` for (i=indice;i<=n-1;i++){
         j=0;
         l2 = strlen(names[i]);
         l1 = strlen(names[i+1]);
         if (l1>l2)
            l=l1;
         else
            l=l2;
        while (j<l){

            names[i][j]=names[i+1][j];
            j++;
       }

    } `